# How to return data in cypher using a condition?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relationship in Neo4j that looks something like this[image]

Where (A)-[:Relationship]->(B) and (B)-[:Relationship]->(C) use the same relationship (in this case :Relationship), and I want to write a cypher query with a condition so that if the count of second level relationships (A)->(C) is greater than x, then don'd display (B)->(C), ie only display (A)->(B).

I tried to do something like:

```
MATCH(A) WHERE id(A)={id}
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(A)-[:Relationship]->(B)
OPTIONAL MATCH q=(A)-[:Relationship]->(B)-[:Relationship]->(C)
RETURN A, p, CASE WHEN COUNT(q)<10 THEN q ELSE [] END AS foo
```

The problem was foo was always q

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered matching an arbitrary path with a maximum length? Something along these lines?

```
MATCH path=(n:Node {name: {id} })-[:RELATIONSHIP*0..9]->(:Node) 
RETURN PATH
```

Alternatively, you could use APOC which would allow you to parameterize the depth of the path.

```
MATCH (one:Node {name : {id} })
CALL apoc.path.expand(one, "RELATIONSHIP>", "+Node", 0, {n}) YIELD path AS p
return p
```

If you wanted to find all of the nodes at a particular depth `{n}` from a starting node but then only return them if they were less than a specific threshold `{lim}` then you could do something like this

```
MATCH (one:Node {name : {id} })
CALL apoc.path.expand(one,"RELATIONSHIP>","+Node", 0, {n}) yield path as p
WITH collect(nodes(p)[{n}]) AS nodes_at_depth
RETURN 
CASE 
  WHEN size(nodes_at_depth) < {lim} then nodes_at_depth
  ELSE []
END AS nodes_at_depth
```

Alternatively, you could just return the first `{lim}` nodes at that depth

```
MATCH (one:Node {name : {id} })
CALL apoc.path.expand(one,"RELATIONSHIP>","+Node", 0, {n}) yield path as p
WITH collect(nodes(p)[{n}]) AS nodes_at_depth
RETURN nodes_at_depth[0..{lim}]
```

Comment: In our case, we want to display as much data as possible, but not so much that it becomes convoluted. Thats why in some case showing C is important, but when we have too much data, we would like to refine it.

Comment: However, is there a way to do a CASE-like conditional statement where we can limit the number of links within the relationship statement?

Comment: You can just change the upper bound in the query  (e.g. `[:RELATIONSHIP*0..5]`)

Comment: Yes, but how can I do that dynamically? ie COUNT(q) = 4 means [:RELATIONSHIP*0..2],  bu tCOUNT(q) = 10 means [:RELATIONSHIP*0..1]

Comment: I am not following your examples... `COUNT(q) = 10` means `[:RELATIONSHIP*0..1]`.  You could use an APOC CALL to path.expand to parameterize the query depth.  Beyond that you might need to actually update your question with a little representative sample data and a sample of the desired result of your query.

Comment: I think maybe i just understood. You want to match to some depth `n` but only return `n - x`? Is that right?

Comment: More like match the number of incidents of depth 2, and select x or y depending on the result. Additionally, in this case x or y would be result sets, x being the result of q and y being an empty set.

Comment: Hey Dave, I decided to go a different route all together give me lack of expertise in the matter, but I want to thank you for your help and the time you dedicated to helping me out, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply adding a WHERE on your OPTIONAL MATCH so it will only display when the number of relationships is below your threshold?

```
MATCH(A) WHERE id(A)={id}
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(A)-[:Relationship]->(B)
OPTIONAL MATCH q=(A)-[:Relationship]->(B)-[:Relationship]->(C)
WHERE size((B)-[:Relationship]->()) < 10
RETURN A, p, CASE WHEN q IS NULL THEN [] ELSE q END AS foo
```

It's important to remember that WHERE clauses only apply to the previous MATCH, OPTIONAL MATCH, or WITH, so in this case, the OPTIONAL MATCH will fail and `q` will be null when the number of secondary relationships from `B` exceeds your threshold.